# Generate forms from output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view which list all the attachments for a project

```
<% @project.project_attachments.each do |project_attachment| %>
<p>
<b><%= check_box_tag(project_attachment.name.to_sym) %>
<a href="<%= project_attachment.attachment %>"><%=(project_attachment.name)%></a>    </b>
</p>
<% end %>



<%= link_to 'Parse',  {:controller => "projects", :action => "parse" } %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

What I am trying to do is when user click on parse, it should call controller parse, and pass long all the "checked" attachment names. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them all in the same `form_tag`, and make them like this:

```
check_box_tag('project_attachments[]',project_attachment.id)
```

Also, make `Parse` the submit button of said form.

In the controller, `params[:project_attachments]` will be an array containing all `id`s of the checked project attachments. Just pay attention that if no project attachment was checked, `params[:project_attachments]` will be `nil` rather than an empty array.